# iphone development: facebook app prevents opening my app automatically after login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a strange problem with facebook login. In my app I use facebook login and it was working quite well until I find a strange bug. Well, when there is no facebook app on my phone, when I want to login, I login through safari and then my app opens automatically with no problem. On the other hand if the facebook app for iphone is installed, when I try to login, the Facebook app automatically opens and asks for facebook credidentals. When I enter them It stays in the Facebook app and does not turn back to my app. However, If the facebook app already has the credidentals, my app opens immediately with no problem.

So the expected behaviour is when I enter the credidentals, my app should be opened automatically. How can I do that? Otherwise, is there a way to disable authenticating via facebook app but and only using safari?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Bundle ID and other properties on Facebook Developer. Make sure they are fully mapped to the data provided in your plist like so:

[image]